# Rails: Correct routing for namespaced resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If you add a resource map to a namespace in your `routes.rb` in Rails 2.3, how do you make `link_to` (and `form_for`, etc) understand that it should get the namespaced controller instead of one in the root namespace?

For example...

With this in `routes.rb`:

```
map.namespace :admin do |admin|
  admin.resources :opt_in_users
end
```

And this in the view:

```
<%= link_to @anOptInUser %>
```

That `link_to` should use `link_for_admin_opt_in_user`, but instead it tries to use `link_for_opt_in_user`, which fails.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With namespaced resources, as with nested resources, you can use an array with a symbol:

```
link_to 'Click here', [:admin, @opt_in_user]
```

or

```
form_for [:admin, @opt_in_user] do |form| ....
```

Comment: It still applies for Rails 3.1.3.

Answer (score 2):

the rails docs for url_for indicate you'd have to call this explicitly:

> If you instead of a hash pass a record
>   (like an Active Record or Active
>   Resource) as the options parameter,
>   you‘ll trigger the named route for
>   that record. The lookup will happen on
>   the name of the class. So passing a
>   Workshop object will attempt to use
>   the workshop_path route. If you have a
>   nested route, such as
>   admin_workshop_path you‘ll have to
>   call that explicitly (it‘s impossible
>   for url_for to guess that route).

(from http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#M001564)

Comment: Yeah, that's what I ended up doing… Thanks for confirming it's the only way! (although I wouldn't agree it's *impossible* for url_for to guess the route if there exists only one!)

Answer (score 0):

Rails can accept an array of objects that are then mapped into a named route

e.g. <%= link_to @comment.title, [@article, @comment] %>

You'll get a link to `/articles/@article.to_param/comments/@article.to_param`

This can be used in `form_for` and other places as well

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
link_to '...', admin_opt_in_user_path(@anOptInUser)
```

For collection:

```
admin_opt_in_users_path
```

You can also add edit and new prefixes.

When you use form_for be sure you pass admin_opt_in_users_path on new action and admin_opt_in_user_path(@anOptInUser) on edit action.